# Pyspark & conda : 'DGEMV' parameter number 6 had an illegal value

Tags: java, apache-spark, pyspark, blas

On spark 3.2:(via conda install)

Just upgraded and now I'm getting:`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ** On entry to 'DGEMV' parameter number 6 had an illegal value`

```
Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2403)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2352)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2351)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2351)        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1109)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1109)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1109)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2591)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2533)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2522)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function (LSHModel$$Lambda$3787/1853968316: (struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>) => array<struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>>)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:759)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:140)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.ShuffleWriteProcessor.write(ShuffleWriteProcessor.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:506)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1462)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:509)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ** On entry to 'DGEMV' parameter number 6 had an illegal value
        at dev.ludovic.netlib.blas.AbstractBLAS.checkArgument(AbstractBLAS.java:46)
        at dev.ludovic.netlib.blas.AbstractBLAS.dgemv(AbstractBLAS.java:345)
        at dev.ludovic.netlib.blas.Java8BLAS.dgemv(Java8BLAS.java:30)
        at dev.ludovic.netlib.blas.AbstractBLAS.dgemv(AbstractBLAS.java:336)
        at dev.ludovic.netlib.blas.Java8BLAS.dgemv(Java8BLAS.java:30)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.BLAS$.gemvImpl(BLAS.scala:631)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.BLAS$.gemv(BLAS.scala:614)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.BLAS$.gemv(BLAS.scala:594)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.BucketedRandomProjectionLSHModel.hashFunction(BucketedRandomProjectionLSH.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.LSHModel.$anonfun$transform$1(LSH.scala:99)
        ... 15 more
```

From commandline Java:

```
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_332"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_332-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.332-b09, mixed mode)
```

My research points to a java mismatch issue, but my java version seems to match. I did not enable native BLAS. Any suggestions welcome.

Tried: setting java home
`export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.332.b09-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre/`
No change.

Buried warning:

```
WARN InstanceBuilder$NativeBLAS: Failed to load implementation from:dev.ludovic.netlib.blas.JNIBLAS
22/07/03 14:00:07 WARN InstanceBuilder$NativeBLAS: Failed to load implementation from:dev.ludovic.netlib.blas.ForeignLinkerBLAS
```

Followed [these directions to use blas with spark](https://gist.github.com/dusenberrymw/d24fcefcd245cfacbc60d3b4caccc560).  (Using native library.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is really just a badly described error message.  I had different sized vectors being compared.  Once I corrected that issue this error message stopped happening.